# Can logia users die of old age?

Tags: one-piece

Can logia fruit users die of old age?  For example, portaguse.d ace. I'm asking this question because logia users are the element of the fruit they eat, and i'm pretty sure  elements can't age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if that was the case, Fire-fist Ace wouldn't have died in the first place.
Logia users aren't always the element -- you can read it [here](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Logia) -- and, yes, Logia eaters can die of old age.

Comment: You might want to edit your answer for clarity, as it seems to start out answering if Logia users can die at all, which isn't the question.